# How to send Parse user's password to external API Request?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, pfuser

I'm developing an iOS app which the user must login/register an account. But this account must be the same used in some external webservice.

The problem is: I want to do some Jobs on Parse to send Push Notifications automatically. To know when Parse Job have to send the Push Notification, I have to login in my external webservice, I mean, I have to send the PFUser Username and Password to my webservice.

So there is a way to obtain the user's password in a plaintext in CloudCode?

Or there is another way to do this?

Comment: No way to see pw's after they're set as logIn or signUp params.  I think the thing you must do is use the other web service as the source of truth on user authentication.  Create your parse.com users with an app-generated password.

Comment: If you own the server then the servers need to trust each other and use the user name / I'd for info without password

Comment: I don't own the other web service. But the way I figure out is not the best in terms of security, but it's a solution. I'm duplicating the password when the user registers on my server. The duplicate password will be encrypt with some AES code. Now, I can use the other web service to decrypt the password and send to another API Request. I know, it's not the best but it's the only solution for now. But thank you both for the info.